# Where can I find an XSD or DTD for the XSLT 1.0 specification?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Does such a thing exist?

I have a customer files that are apparently invalid XSLT (the .Net XSLTransform cannot read them) but I do not have any useful error message to go on.  I was thinking that if there was a DTD or XSD I could at least validate his transforms.

Thanks

---

Soon after posting this, a work collegue pointed out that Visual studio 2010 installs several such schema in this (default) folder: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas**.

It looks like MS have derived their own XSD from [this DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dtd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unofficial DTD for XSLT 1.0 [here](http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform) ([Direct link](http://www.w3.org/1999/11/xslt10.dtd))

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I also discovered that a suitable XSD comes with visual studio - see edits in my question